# Python CSV: How to extract data with condition from Dataframe, edit the extracted data then put it back into the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Sample csv data:

```
ID,AC_Input_Voltage,AC_Input_Current,DC_Output_Voltage,DC_Output_Current,DC_Output_Power,Input_Active_Power,Input_Reactive_Power,Input_Apparent_Power,Line_Frequency,DC_Ref,AC_Ref,Time_Stamp
8301,418,13.2,34.4,136,4673,1,-1,5524.5,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:00
8301,419.3,2.3,0.7,-0.9,-0.6,1,-1,946.2,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:01
8301,417.7,15.2,30.3,196.5,5962,1,-1,6355,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:02
8301,418.7,2.3,0.7,-0.9,-0.6,1,-1,944.7,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:03
8301,419.3,3.4,53.6,10.8,580.2,1,-1,1432.8,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:04
8301,417.7,13.6,30.1,170.4,5122.7,1,-1,5681.8,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:05
8301,418,11.5,41.2,105,4328.2,1,-1,4796.9,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:07
8301,419.7,2.3,0.8,-0.9,-0.7,1,-1,946.9,0,51,0,22/6/2017 05:11:08
8301,419.7,2.3,40.6,-0.7,-27.9,1,-1,974,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:09
8301,417.4,14.9,30.4,194.4,5903.8,1,-1,6215.4,0,51,0,22/6/2017 05:11:10
8301,417.7,14.7,30.5,186.2,5682.9,1,-1,6139.5,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:11
8301,418,12,31.5,141.5,4456.9,1,-1,5012.5,0,51,0,22/6/2017 05:11:12
8301,419,2.3,0.7,-1.4,-0.9,1,-1,945.4,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:13
8301,419,2.3,0.7,-0.9,-0.6,1,-1,945.4,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:14
8301,419.7,2.3,0.8,-0.9,-0.7,1,-1,946.9,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:15
8301,419,2.3,0.7,-0.9,-0.6,1,-1,945.4,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:16
8301,419,2.3,32.9,-0.2,-5.7,1,-1,972.4,0,51,0,22/6/2017 05:11:17
8301,419.3,2.3,50.3,0.3,17.3,1,-1,973.2,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:18
8301,417.4,15.2,30.5,197.4,6010.5,1,-1,6350,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:19
8301,418.7,2.3,0.9,-0.9,-0.7,1,-1,944.7,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:20
8301,419,2.3,42.9,-0.2,-7.4,1,-1,972.4,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:21
8301,417.4,13.9,30.4,180,5477.6,1,-1,5811.8,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:22
8301,419.7,2.3,0.9,-0.9,-0.8,1,-1,946.9,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:23
8301,418.7,2.3,0.7,-0.9,-0.6,1,-1,944.7,0,50,0,22/6/2017 05:11:24
8301,418.3,2.3,0.6,-0.9,-0.5,1,-1,943.9,0,49,0,22/6/2017 05:11:25
```

I've tried the following code and manage to edit the data then put them into a new dataframe( `df_filter2` ):

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import date,time,datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
df["Time_Stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time_Stamp"]) # convert to Datetime

def getMask(start,end):
    mask = (df['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (df['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask;

start = '2017-06-22 05:00:00'
end = '2017-06-22 05:20:00'
timerange = df.loc[getMask(start, end)]

df_filter = timerange[timerange["AC_Input_Current"].le(3.0)] # new df with less or equal to 0.5
#print(df_filter)

where = (df_filter[df_filter["Time_Stamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 1] ["Time_Stamp"] - pd.Timedelta("1s")).astype(str).tolist() # Find where diff > 1 second
df_filter2 = timerange[timerange["Time_Stamp"].isin(where)] # Create new df with those
#print(df_filter2)
df_filter2["AC_Input_Current"] = 0.0 # Set c1 to 0.0

#display spikes ( high possibility of data being a spike )
for index, row in df_filter2.iterrows():
    values = row.astype(str).tolist()
    print(','.join(values))
```

**Output:** *Note*: The edited rows below is in the dataframe `df_filter2` ..

```
8301,418.0,0.0,34.4,136.0,4673.0,1,-1,5524.5,0,49,0,2017-06-22 05:11:00
8301,417.7,0.0,30.3,196.5,5962.0,1,-1,6355.0,0,49,0,2017-06-22 05:11:02
8301,418.0,0.0,41.2,105.0,4328.2,1,-1,4796.9,0,49,0,2017-06-22 05:11:07
8301,418.0,0.0,31.5,141.5,4456.9,1,-1,5012.5,0,51,0,2017-06-22 05:11:12
8301,417.4,0.0,30.5,197.4,6010.5,1,-1,6350.0,0,50,0,2017-06-22 05:11:19
8301,417.4,0.0,30.4,180.0,5477.6,1,-1,5811.8,0,49,0,2017-06-22 05:11:22
```

What I want is to put back the output ( from `df_filter2` ) into the main dataframe `df`, replacing the rows from `df` with the same `Time_Stamp`, with the rows from `df_filter2`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make `Time_Stamp` the index for both data frames, then assign `df` to `df_filter2` values, based on matching indices.

First, ensure both data frames have `Time_Stamp` in the same format, as well as identical column names.  For the sample data provided, I used:

```
# copy df sample data from OP
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", parse_dates=["Time_Stamp"])
# now copy df_filter2 sample data
df_filter2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", header=None, names=df.columns, parse_dates=[12])
```

Now, set `Time_Stamp` as index and replace matching rows:

```
df = df.set_index("Time_Stamp")
df_filter2 = df_filter2.set_index("Time_Stamp")
df.loc[df_filter2.index] = df_filter2
```

**UPDATE** (per comments)
To be explicit, here's a full working example, starting with a `data` dict, building `df`, and using OP code to generate `df_filter2`.  Only slight modifications made (e.g. defining `Time_Stamp` as `pd.Timestamp` in the original `data`, and adding `.loc` in places).

```
# sample data
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

data = {'AC_Input_Current': {0: 13.199999999999999, 1: 2.2999999999999998,2: 15.199999999999999,3: 2.2999999999999998,4: 3.3999999999999999,5: 13.6,6: 11.5,7: 2.2999999999999998,8: 2.2999999999999998,9: 14.9,10: 14.699999999999999,11: 12.0,12: 2.2999999999999998,13: 2.2999999999999998,14: 2.2999999999999998,15: 2.2999999999999998,16: 2.2999999999999998,17: 2.2999999999999998,18: 15.199999999999999,19: 2.2999999999999998,20: 2.2999999999999998,21: 13.9,22: 2.2999999999999998,23: 2.2999999999999998,24: 2.2999999999999998},
'AC_Input_Voltage': {0: 418.0,1: 419.30000000000001,2: 417.69999999999999,3: 418.69999999999999,4: 419.30000000000001,5: 417.69999999999999,6: 418.0,7: 419.69999999999999,8: 419.69999999999999,9: 417.39999999999998,10: 417.69999999999999,11: 418.0,12: 419.0,13: 419.0,14: 419.69999999999999,15: 419.0,16: 419.0,17: 419.30000000000001,18: 417.39999999999998,19: 418.69999999999999,20: 419.0,21: 417.39999999999998,22: 419.69999999999999,23: 418.69999999999999,24: 418.30000000000001},
'DC_Output_Current': {0: 136.0,1: -0.90000000000000002,2: 196.5,3: -0.90000000000000002,4: 10.800000000000001,5: 170.40000000000001,6: 105.0,7: -0.90000000000000002,8: -0.69999999999999996,9: 194.40000000000001,10: 186.19999999999999,11: 141.5,12: -1.3999999999999999,13: -0.90000000000000002,14: -0.90000000000000002,15: -0.90000000000000002,16: -0.20000000000000001,17: 0.29999999999999999,18: 197.40000000000001,19: -0.90000000000000002,20: -0.20000000000000001,21: 180.0,22: -0.90000000000000002,23: -0.90000000000000002,24: -0.90000000000000002},
'DC_Output_Power': {0: 4673.0,1: -0.59999999999999998,2: 5962.0,3: -0.59999999999999998,4: 580.20000000000005,5: 5122.6999999999998,6: 4328.1999999999998,7: -0.69999999999999996,8: -27.899999999999999,9: 5903.8000000000002,10: 5682.8999999999996,11: 4456.8999999999996,12: -0.90000000000000002,13: -0.59999999999999998,14: -0.69999999999999996,15: -0.59999999999999998,16: -5.7000000000000002,17: 17.300000000000001,18: 6010.5,19: -0.69999999999999996,20: -7.4000000000000004,21: 5477.6000000000004,22: -0.80000000000000004,23: -0.59999999999999998,24: -0.5},
'DC_Output_Voltage': {0: 34.399999999999999,1: 0.69999999999999996,2: 30.300000000000001,3: 0.69999999999999996,4: 53.600000000000001,5: 30.100000000000001,6: 41.200000000000003,7: 0.80000000000000004,8: 40.600000000000001,9: 30.399999999999999,10: 30.5,11: 31.5,12: 0.69999999999999996,13: 0.69999999999999996,14: 0.80000000000000004,15: 0.69999999999999996,16: 32.899999999999999,17: 50.299999999999997,18: 30.5,19: 0.90000000000000002,20: 42.899999999999999,21: 30.399999999999999,22: 0.90000000000000002,23: 0.69999999999999996,24: 0.59999999999999998},
 'DC_Ref': {0: 49,1: 50,2: 49,3: 50,4: 49,5: 50,6: 49,7: 51,8: 49,9: 51,10: 49,11: 51,12: 49,13: 50,14: 50,15: 49,16: 51,17: 49,18: 50,19: 49,20: 50,21: 49,22: 50,23: 50,24: 49},
 'Input_Apparent_Power': {0: 5524.5,1: 946.20000000000005,2: 6355.0,3: 944.70000000000005,4: 1432.8,5: 5681.8000000000002,6: 4796.8999999999996,7: 946.89999999999998,8: 974.0,9: 6215.3999999999996,10: 6139.5,11: 5012.5,12: 945.39999999999998,13: 945.39999999999998,14: 946.89999999999998,15: 945.39999999999998,16: 972.39999999999998,17: 973.20000000000005,18: 6350.0,19: 944.70000000000005,20: 972.39999999999998,21: 5811.8000000000002,22: 946.89999999999998,23: 944.70000000000005,24: 943.89999999999998},
'Time_Stamp': {0: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:00'),1: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:01'),2: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:02'),3: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:03'),4: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:04'),5: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:05'),6: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:07'),7: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:08'),8: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:09'),9: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:10'),10: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:11'),11: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:12'),12: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:13'),13: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:14'),14: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:15'),15: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:16'),16: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:17'),17: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:18'),18: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:19'),19: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:20'),20: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:21'),21: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:22'),22: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:23'),23: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:24'),24: Timestamp('2017-06-22 05:11:25')}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

There are a few columns which have constant values:

```
df["AC_Ref"] = 0
df["ID"] = 8301
df["Input_Active_Power"] = 1
df["Input_Reactive_Power"] = -1
df["Line_Frequency"] = 0
```

Now construct `df_filter2`:

```
def getMask(start,end):
    mask = (df['Time_Stamp'] > start) & (df['Time_Stamp'] <= end)
    return mask;
start = '2017-06-22 05:00:00'
end = '2017-06-22 05:20:00'
timerange = df.loc[getMask(start, end)]
df_filter = timerange.loc[timerange["AC_Input_Current"].le(3.0)]
where = (df_filter.loc[df_filter["Time_Stamp"].diff().dt.total_seconds() > 1, "Time_Stamp"] - pd.Timedelta("1s")).astype(str).tolist() 
df_filter2 = timerange.loc[timerange["Time_Stamp"].isin(where)].copy() 
df_filter2["AC_Input_Current"] = 0.0
```

Finally, replace rows in `df` with matching rows (by `Time_Stamp`) from `df_filter2`:

```
df = df.set_index("Time_Stamp")
df_filter2 = df_filter2.set_index("Time_Stamp")
df.loc[df_filter2.index] = df_filter2
```

We can check to be sure the replacement has occurred:

```
assert(all(df.AC_Input_Current.sort_values()[:5].values == df_filter2.AC_Input_Current.values))
```

Comment: Instead of using `pd.read_clipboard`, what if i were to us `read_csv` for `df = df.read_csv('MainD2.csv',sep=',', parse_dates=["Time_Stamp"])`, how do I change for `df_filter2` ? Sorry about that, I'm still learning python so yeah..

Comment: Your code already generates `df_filter2` once you have `df`.  Just use that.

Comment: I've tried the codes you have given and I went to check the data in `df` to see if the rows from `df_filter2`, where the `AC_Input_Current` value was set to 0, is in the `df`...  apparently it wasn't . as the `AC_Input_Current`  value was still `2.3`

Comment: With the sample data you provided, it works on my end.  I'll update my post to include the full code with data and output.  Can you confirm that running my code, including building `df` from the dict I've included, works for you too?

Comment: yes it works if I were to use your answer along with the `df` from the dict you included.